# How to have multiple if statements inside a function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to do this in Clojure:

```
int i=1;j=2;k=3;
str r;
cin>>r;
if(r=="A")
cout<<i; (i.e., print 1)
if(r=="J")
cout<<j; (i.e., print 2)
if(r=="K")
cout<<k; (i.e., print 3)
else
do something else
```

I am doing it like this in clojure:

```
(defn str-to-num [c]
    (if ( = (str (first c )) "A")
        1
    (java.lang.Integer/valueOf (str (first c))))

(if ( = (str (first c )) "J")
        2
    (java.lang.Integer/valueOf (str (first c))))

(if ( = (str (first c )) "K")
        3
    (java.lang.Integer/valueOf (str (first c))))

)
```

But, I'm getting an error. Could someone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: NumberFormatException For input string: "A"  java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString (NumberFormatException.java:48)

Comment: If I have only one if statement, say only: (if ( = (str (first c )) "A")
        1
    (java.lang.Integer/valueOf (str (first c))))
then it works fine. Whats happening?

Comment: It works fine if you use "A" as your input, but it fails for everything else.

Comment: the clojure-core.logic tag here is totally irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the if blocks are run, one after the other, regardless of what any of them return. If you want if / else / chaining you should use `cond` or `case` (though the two branches of a standard if work fine if there are only two options).

Your first two if blocks can't do anything meaningful except throw an error. And that is exactly what will happen for most inputs.

"A", "J", and "K" are not valid numbers, so trying to parse them will throw an error.

The only meaningful things this function can do is return the first letter of a string as a number if it is parsible as one.

```
user> (str-to-num "A")
NumberFormatException For input string: "A"  java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString (NumberFormatException.java:65)
user> (str-to-num "J")
NumberFormatException For input string: "J"  java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString (NumberFormatException.java:65)
user> (str-to-num "K")
NumberFormatException For input string: "K"  java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString (NumberFormatException.java:65)
user> (str-to-num "100")
1
```

perhaps you wanted something like:

```
user> (defn str-to-num [c]
        (case (first c)
              \A 1
              \J 2
              \K 3
              (int (first c))))
#'user/str-to-num
user> (str-to-num "A")
1
user> (str-to-num "J")
2
user> (str-to-num "K")
3
user> (str-to-num "L")
76
user> (str-to-num "☃")
9731
```

Alternately:

```
user> (defn str-to-num [c]
        (case (first c)
              \A 1
              \J 2
              \K 3
              (Integer/parseInt (subs c 0 1))))
#'user/str-to-num
user> (str-to-num "9")
9
```

Comment: So when I did (str-to-num "AR"), it's still giving the same error!!

Comment: Try inputting "AR". Because I'm getting that error, and I want to give two characters as input, like "2B", "AD", "3F"; if first character is A, J, K etc. then it will return those numbers, else it will return the given number (from the first character) like 2, 3 etc from above.

Comment: user> (str-to-num "AR") => 1

Comment: it only looks at the first character of the string, either matching \A, \J, \K or parsing as an int.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the form of your if statement

You have

```
(if ( = (str (first c )) "A")
    1
(java.lang.Integer/valueOf (str (first c))))
```

The form of if is

```
(if (cond)
    trueResult
    falseResult)
```

So your "working version" will return 1 if you input A. If you input any other string, it actually throws an error. But, if an error were not thrown, all three if statements would be executed, and the result of the last one is actually returned.

This is closer to your C++ code:

```
(defn str-to-num [c]
    (if ( = (str (first c )) "A") (print 1))
    (if ( = (str (first c )) "J") (print 2))
    (if ( = (str (first c )) "K") (print 3)))
```